# Wondering how to direct out into array then output from array

Tags: java, arrays, cubes

I am having to write a program that loads the first 10 integers' into an array. I've tried it every way and have not been able to make it work with an array.  This is as far as I have gotten.

```
public class midtermcube2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totz;
        for (int numz=0; numz<=9;numz++)
        {
            totz=numz*numz*numz;
            System.out.println(totz);
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation improved for readability

Comment: What have you tried in regard to appending to an array? So far looks like you are successfully printing the cubed ints.

Comment: Instead of this code which works, add to your question the code showing the unsuccessful attempts you have made to integrate an array.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class AddArray
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[]=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=i;
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}   
}
```